# Issue with Sending Email with SharePoint Event Receiver (Email generates space in LINK)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have developed an Event Receiver which works by sending an email to users and this email contains a link (Link to particular Page). This Email Link Generates SPACE while email is Send to users (Link with space not working).

While sending an email through Event Receiver i have tried removing spaces. for ex:

> strEmailURLLink =
>   string.Format("{0}/SitePages/HierarchyCertLevel3.aspx?CType=PAM&uid={1}&seg={2}&bs={3}&pg={4}",
>   Web.Url.ToString().Trim(),
>   strThreadName.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty),
>   lvSegment.LookupId.ToString().Trim(),
>   lvBusinessScenario.LookupId.ToString().Trim(),
>   lvProcessGroup.LookupId.ToString().Trim());

It generates space at "SitePages/HierarchyCertLevel3.asp x" (asp x) which can not be handled and when it comes to the query string it also creates the spaces but it handlable.

I have found on tricky behavior where email sending works properly with CodeBehind of page but fails while sending an email through Event Receiver.

Comment: I have used anchor tag in a Mail Body to navigate to the URL. what I have observed is anchor tag itself generating space in a link. Code for same is below: strMessage.Append("This activity is being facilitated through a Questionnaire. <a href='" + strEmailURLLink.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty) + "' target='_blank'> <b> Click Here </b> </a> to launch the Review Questionnaire ");

strEmailURLLink = This variable contains the URL of page with QueryString. When I simply concat it with mail body it work properly without any spaces in a link but when i bind it with anchor tag, I didnt.